# When adding Firebase to project, gradle complains about multiple support library versions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-support-library

Since I started this project (not so long ago) I've added the support library with the newest version (27.0.2 right now). I'm in the process of adding Firebase as a new dependency. The problem I'm having that gradle now complains that I have 2 different versions of the support library (27.0.2 and 25.2.0). Since 27.0.2 is added by myself, 25.2.0 must come from Firebase. Before adding Firebase my project was fine, but when I synced gradle after adding Firebase it showed this warning.

How can I fix this? I'm already using the newest Firebase version (11.8.0) and the newest google-services from gms (com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0)

By the way, I don't want to revert my own support library version to 25.2.0. I want to keep it at 27.0.2.

Comment: Manually include `27.0.2` versions of the artifacts that Firebase is trying to use `25.2.0` for, and Gradle will choose the newer one.

Comment: Please Check this first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46306582/421467 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/421467 .

Comment: @CommonsWare That worked, thanks! Can you write an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @Mr.Hyde CommonsWare answer worked, but I think that's the same as your second link. So I upvoted that one as well

Comment: @PeterHaddad I had to add support-media-compat and support-v4 because Firebase had the version 25.2.0 included for that one instead of 27.0.2

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, maybe marking it as a duplicate is better than writing another answer. Thanks for the help though!